# Highrise API Username Issue

Tags: .net, curl, highrise

Working with the Highrise API .net wrapper, and alternatively using curl to test the Highrise API. Followed the instructions so far to the best my abilities, but I'm still running into issues with getting a valid request through. At the moment, I seem to be have an issue with sending a basic request to the API, because the username, that I believe I'm supposed to be using, is an email address. When using my email address as the username I get the following error from curl:

curl -u [AuthKey]:X https://peterbue@domain-name.com.highrisehq.com/people.xml

curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'domain-name.com.highrisehq.com'

It seems to me that I shouldn't be using my email address as my username, because it is causing the URI to be incorrectly resolved. When I look at what my username could be instead, I find nothing.

Comment: Try with `-k`/`--insecure` in your command.

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem could be the wrong credentials (token and account) that you use.

You use https://peterbue@domain-name.com.highrisehq.com/people.xml, but the url should be something like https://peterbue.highrisehq.com/people.xml

You can find the token in Settings > My Info > API Token and the account in your subdomain, for example if you have the this subdomain: http://subdomain.highrisehq.com, the account is **subdomain**.

For more details take a look [HERE](https://help.highrisehq.com/users/api-token/)